# mailto client does not work in mobile devices and blocks the popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, email-client

I am trying to add a mailto button to send an email using email client 
Here is my code:

```
    clickEmail(e) {

    let storyId = this.refs.storyToEmail.getAttribute('id');
    if (storyId != undefined) {
        let urlToSend = this.createURL(storyId) + "?ref=emailShare";
        let subjectLine = "Shared story - " + this.props.headline;
        let hrefValue = "mailto:?subject=".concat(subjectLine, "&body=", "I thought you might find this interesting:%0D%0A %0D%0A", urlToSend, "%0D%0A %0D%0AConnecting Communitie %0D%0A %0D%0A");

        let email = this.refs.storyToEmail;
        email.href = hrefValue;
        return email.href;
    }
}
```

However this works for me and almost all desktops and not working on many mobile devices.
After searching I noticed it needs permission from the browser as follows:
https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/set-gmail-as-browser-default-email-client-ht

But the issue is I cannot find anyway to do the setting as suggested in the link for mobile(chrome)?

Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: Did you test normal `mailto` link without javascript first? Maybe your device is not properly set up. On my phone, clicking mailto links opens GMail app.

Comment: @TomášZato Thanks for the answer. That is the point. I know there is something wrong with browser set up and needs permission and I am able even to do the set up following the instruction provided in the link I posted above but for phone I cannot see any way to do the setup

Comment: Most people probably have it set up, so if you need this for testing, maybe just try different browser. You could spend several hours messing with chrome settings instead of doing the actual app you want to work on.